# php md5 for login won't let me login, and keeps saying password incorrect

Tags: php, authentication, md5

The md5 is posting to the database from the signup page so I know that's working, but everything I try here won't let me sign in and just keeps telling me I have the wrong password.

```
 <?php 
// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if (isset($_POST["user_name"]) ) {

        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user_name"]);      
        $pass_word = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST["pass_word"]));
   $pass_word=md5($pass_word);

    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "../connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT m_id FROM member WHERE user_name='$user' AND pass_word='$pass_word' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
     // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["m_id"];
     }
         $_SESSION["m_id"] = $id;
         $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
         $_SESSION["pass_word"] = $pass_word;

         header("location: ../../index.php");
         exit();
    } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a     href="member_login.php">Click Here</a>'; 
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you write `session_start()` at the top of your page??

Comment: you have two times used `md5()` on `$_POST['pass_word']`

Comment: do you intentionally use md5 twice on the user's password? If the password is stored in md5 format in the member table then surely you only need to md5 hash the supplied password once?

Comment: You're also potentially *changing* the password (with `mysql_real_escape_string()`) before running it through the MD5 hash algorithm.

Answer (score -2):

You're running MD5 twice on your password.

```
$pass_word = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST["pass_word"]));
$pass_word = md5($pass_word);
```

Also, don't use MD5, it is completely unsafe, look into using bcrypt, it is secure, and very easy to implement in PHP. Replacing MD5 with this line of code will make your password hashes safe. Preferably add some salt, the salt being some random string. It will make breaking your passwords nigh impossible.

```
$hash = password_hash($password . $salt, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Answer (score -3):

Change these lines from

```
$pass_word = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST["pass_word"]));
$pass_word=md5($pass_word);
```

to

```
$pass_word=md5($_POST["pass_word"]);
```